# sql join issue problem

Tags: sql

I have 3 columns in a table say test with columns say col1,col2,col3, they are foreign keys of a sigle table say test_master...how to write query to get desc column from test_master for those col1,col2,col3 in test.

example

```
test table
col1 col2 col3
100  101  102

test_master table
id   desc
100  testdata1 
101  testdata1 
102  testdata1 
103  testdata1
```

help please...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do three joins on the same table:

```
  select tm1.desc, tm2.desc, tm3.desc
  from test t
  join test_master tm1 on t.col1=tm1.id
  join test_master tm2 on t.col2=tm2.id
  join test_master tm3 on t.col3=tm3.id
```

Comment: I thought of above, shall we do it with a single join?

Comment: You can't do it with a single join, because you need 3 different rows in test_master.

Comment: I am not sure about it whether it works or not...the above joins 3 times, will it be a problem for query performance ?

Comment: Not especially - multiple joins on the same table are not particularly unusual. I can't think of a better way of doing it.

Comment: If you have indexes on the col1,col2,col3 and id columns, there shouldn't be any performance issue at all.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are looking at having each column in test table be a row in the output, or what database you are using, but you could use a union:

```
select t.col1, tm.desc from test t left outer join test_master tm on
(t.col1=tm.id)
union all
select t.col2, tm.desc from test t left outer join test_master tm on
(t.col2=tm.id)
union all
select t.col3, tm.desc from test t left outer join test_master tm on
(t.col3=tm.id);
```

Answer (score 0):

This works, but may not be good on performance, depending on the size of your data sets.

```
CREATE TABLE test 
(col1 int, col2 int, col3 int)

INSERT INTO test
VALUES (101,102,103)

CREATE TABLE test_master
( id int, [desc] varchar(20))

INSERT INTO test_master
SELECT 100, 'testdata1'
UNION ALL SELECT 101, 'testdata1'
UNION ALL SELECT 102, 'testdata1'
UNION ALL SELECT 103, 'testdata1'

SELECT tm.id, [desc]
FROM test t
JOIN test_master tm ON tm.id IN (t.col1,t.col2,t.col3)
```

The results:

```
id  desc
101 testdata1
102 testdata1
103 testdata1
```